# Azure AD B2C on backend or front end?

Tags: azure, entra-id, single-sign-on

I have a service oriented application where the fornt end is a NextJs application and the backend is a .net core API project.

I want to use Azure AD B2C to provide Authentication.

Should I configure AD on the front end to perform the login and send the token to the backend api or should I do it on the API backend side?

In particular, If I configure also Google login, Can it be done on the APIs with AD b2c?

Answer (score 0):

You need a UI to redirect to the login page and get the token, so you should do this on the front end.